# Group answers & index based on Questions in python

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as such for analysis purpose, I need to create a list of dictionaries as:

***TARGET OUTPUT***

```
[
{ 'is my anti hiv test conclusive or--Bla bla': [0, 1, 2] }, 
{'I have some hip pain 9 weeks--bla bla': [3, 4, 5, 6]} 
]
```

**Here the list is indices of answers and not the actual answers**

[image]

Well yes, the obvious method is to use groupby but facing some errors

[image]

I tried printing before converting to list. And it seems fine actually,

[image]

Can y'all please help me figure out it's correct syntax so I could to my targeted output.

[Dataset link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LasseRegin/medical-question-answer-data/master/questionDoctorQAs.json)
If somebody needs the shared notebook link, let me know in the comments.

Comment: "but facing some errors". Can you be more specific? What errors are you sticking with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually select the column (`"index"`) whose values you want to appear in the list:

```
df_ans = data.groupby(["question_text"])["index"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

instead of

```
df_ans = data.groupby(["question_text"]).apply(list).to_dict()
```

Otherwise you get a list of the columns, as in your example. That's what happens when you convert a DataFrame to a list, i.e. `list(data)` gives you the same as `list(data.columns)` .